# unique slug routing with different controllers in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have a use case where i want to use similar slug urls for different controller routes
like

```
[Route("~/{prodSlug:prod}")]
ControllerAction1

[Route("~/{CatSlug:cat}")]
ControllerAction2

[Route("~/{users:user}")]
ControllerAction3
```

etc....

now i have defined different custom constraints and they match true or false based on database dictionary
but still i am getting error when request is completed.

```
Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.

The request has found the following matching controller types:
MrnMrsPetFoodFront.Controllers.CategoryController
MrnMrsPetFoodFront.Controllers.ProductController
```

the reason i saw for this is mvc is not stopping once a route was found in categoryconstraint and went on with products and others till end
is their anyway to stop this once a match is found or not possible with mvc 5?
I know i can feed route constraints on ***RouteConfig*** and build a regex based match, but that will only work with application startup and is not a viable solution when the number of links can go up to 10k or 50k or more with time.

Comment: If you have similar routing with same parameter names but different types, specifying the type on the template should be enough to allow you to have multiple actions with the same route assuming each action consume a different data type for each parameter. If this isn't enough, I think you should re-evaluate your use-case.

Comment: the use case is about how you handle stuff in a cms system with permalinks, the problem with approaches i found on different SO questions is that they take care of get but wont work in case of post,put or delete. i am aware of type based routes, but thats why i created custom constraints to specify difference in routes.

Comment: ok i just checked this use case works fine in mvc6 (core version), i will wait for more inputs if its possible in mvc5 or not else i will upgrade my project